# DXA issue while rendering images

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.4

When I am rendering images in my DXA 1.4 views by using `Html.Media(ModelImageField)` it is **distorting** images and creating image with different size in file system and rendering it in view.

I have tried passing width factor as well `Html.Media(ModelImageField, "62")`, but seems it is also creating a image of some different size. Then, I have tried it by simply using `<img src="@ModelImageField.Url" />`, this is rendering correct size of image.

I have to render images of fixed size in my view. Can anyone suggest if I can get image of specific size by passing some parameter to helper function `Html.Media(ModelImageField, "62")`? I have already tried unsuccessfully by passing widthfactor and aspect ratio. Can anyone suggest if I am missing anything. Thanks in advance.

Specific example for issue:

I have a multimedia component with image file (`ZX_series_background_373x140`) attached of size 373x140px (width x height). It is exactly same as I have to show in the view.

When I use `Html.Media(ModelImageField)` it is creating file with name like `ZX_series_background_373x140_tcm8-112358_w1024_h633_n.jpg` of size 227x140px. I am not sure why it is changing width and height of image. I am not sure if I am missing something in parameter. Even when I pass the `WidthFactor` as required width (373px) in that case too, name of file changed as `ZX_series_background_373x140_tcm8-112358_w640_h396_n.jpg` but size is still same 227x140px.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DXA has built-in server-side responsive image resizing (to not send unnecessarily large images to mobile devices) based on device parameters and width and aspect ratio parameters specified in the View code.

See https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Statics/BinaryFileManager.cs

Not sure what you mean exactly with "distorting" images? Do they look really bad?

If you get very low-res images, there may be a problem with obtaining the device/context claims. If you turn on DEBUG log level, your DXA log file should have information about the retrieved context claims.

Comment: Thanks for your response Rick. I have added a specific example of my issue. Here distorted means, as the file of image is changing here so quality is also changing. Am I missing anything?

Comment: OK, if you want to ensure the original image is served, you can indeed render the `img` tag yourself, as you mentioned. The image file should get cached in that case too (see `BinaryFileManager` implementation; if there is no "dimension" suffix in the URL, the image won't get resized, but it will get cached).

Comment: Thanks Rick. I can use img tag to show same image and yes I can see a cached version of same size. Can you also suggest for additional part of my question: In case of image with different size, can we get image of specific size by passing some parameter to helper function `Html.Media(ModelImageField, "62")`?

Comment: You can't prevent image resizing if you use `Html.Media` (or `Url.GetResponsiveImageUrl` for that matter). You can specify an absolute width, but that is only used as a guideline.  For the complete algorithm of how image width/height is determined, see https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Mvc/Html/BaseMediaHelper.cs